# How to get list of cache items with specific prefix and value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am inserting the session id to the cache with the `$user_id` as the value for every user session:

```
Cache::put('session_test_' . $session_id ,$user_id, $seconds);
```

If a user logs from multiple browsers for example, he should have multiple cache items with his `$user_id` as the value.

How can I retrieve all the cache items that have the `session_test_` prefix and the `$user_id` value?

Comment: You can only retrieve data using the key, in this case: `session_test_$session_id`, so you should not use `session_test_$session_id`, but ``session_test_$user_id`, and if the user has multiple sessions, store an array of sessions ids (update the content of this key every time there is a new session). Still, you should not be doing this as laravel already handles sessions with `Redis` if you select the right driver: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#redis